# Is there a good free (prefrerably PDF) bash tutorial online?

Tags: bash

I am finding myself doing a lot more messing around with scripts than I used to and my lack of knowledge in this area (and linux sysadmin/security in general), is becoming a hindrance.

Can anyone recommend a good online resource for bash scripting/linux admin. Preferably, it will be in pdf format, so I can copy it (single file) onto my PDA.

Comment: Come on, at least *pretend* to use Google...

Comment: I have to ask - why PDF?

Comment: @ignatio: of course, I did use Google. But there are so many of them to choose from. The vast majority are sub standard (e.g. written by a high school teacher) or someone who is just starting out him/herself (kinda like a 'Curious George For Bash'). I wanted to know which tutorial the professionals on here recommended.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams - Googling often fails or leads people down the wrong path. That's why StackOverflow exists. If StackOverflow's goal is to become a repository of knowledge, then questions like this are perfectly legitimate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've learnt much from the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

This guide is targeted more at programming beginners, but it can prove useful too:
[Bash Guide for Beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/).

I usually use the HTML version as a reference when hacking Bash, but there is a PDF version of both guides if you want to read them all through. You can find all formats of the guides at http://www.tldp.org/guides.html

Answer (score 11):

The available PDF manuals are very limited. I download some of these HTML guides using something like `wget --page-requisites --mirror --convert-links` so I can read them on the train on my laptop.

- [The Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). Covers a range of topics, from basic to advanced.
- [The Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) is okay, but it's just a reference manual. I read it, but I am sometimes left with unanswered questions. This is a pretty official document, and other guides often refer to this document.
- [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/). Despite the name, this is a great reference for experienced users also.
- [BASH Frequently Asked Questions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/) is a great resource
- [The Bash-Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) is an excellent resource and is filled with all sorts of useful topics. The [Syntax Guide](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/start) is great and often better syntax reference then the Bash Reference Manual.
- Vivek Gite has some great articles at cyberciti.biz. See [bash.cyberciti.biz](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/) and [www.cyberciti.biz/faq/category/bash-shell/](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/category/bash-shell/)

Answer (score 3):

Do not miss to look at
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) - for PDF versions do a bit a of Googling.